# How to display all files from blob mysql (image, txt, pdf)

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I display an images from the database like that:

```
$file = '<a class="" href="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $rows['file']) . '">link</a>';
```

I'm looking for a way to display all types of files (.txt, .pdf, etc…) from the database.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

For each link, you can get the file extension first and then use a different method of displaying each file type appropriately. For example, you can use the FPDF file view to open all .pdf links and for .jpeg links you can just load the base64 into the url. If you are trying to view a .txt or other plain text file type, you can simply echo or print the file into the browser. For PDF's, there is no real way to just echo it to the browser so you will either have to figure out how to render it on your own or use something like FPDF.

Comment: Well this is the simple idea, thank you - is there a code to check file extension from database ,like ** if (file extension==PDF) {do some thing} **

Comment: Yes, you can always just split the string based on the `explode()` function. You can then just get the second element and read that!